# Images in FlatList not displayed

Tags: javascript, firebase, image, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using react native and firebase to create an application that's somewhat similar to a social network. In the profile screen I am trying to display the images that the user posted in a FlatList that has 3 columns. My problem is, when trying to display the images so that they occupy the full width of the FlatList, they don't seem to get displayed. However, when I set a fixed height, they do. I would like to make it so that they are shown with a 1/1 aspect ratio without having to fix a height.

This is my code:

```
            <View style={styles.galleryContainer}>
                <FlatList
                    numColumns={3}
                    horizontal={false}
                    data={posts}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                            <Image
                                style={styles.image}
                                source={{ uri: item.downloadURL }}
                            />
                        </View>
                    )}
                />
            </View>
```

And the styles:

```
    galleryContainer: {
        flex: 1
    },
    image: {
        flex: 1,
        aspectRatio: 1/1,
        height: 120

    },
    imageContainer: {
        flex: 1 / 3
    }
```

I have tried setting the height to 100% and that did not work either, any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: have you tried setting `width: 120, aspectRatio: 1`?

Comment: Thing is I want to try to avoid to set a fixed width/height, from what I have seen, this can be accomplished by not determining the height or width, but it didn't work for me

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately, with network images, you will have to specify at least one dimension in order to display them. It's a limitation of the RN image component

Comment: Alright thanks! Is there a way to set the size relative to the parent view or to the screen size?

Comment: Try setting `resizeMode='contain'` on the image

Comment: @Kai thanks for the comment but it's not working :(

Comment: The problem in Firebase  URL, check it outside, but layout works fine check here https://snack.expo.io/@ahmed_gaber/sponaneous-tortillas

Comment: @AhmedGaber the URLs are fine, since I am able to show the pictures if I do set the height.

Comment: @AhmedGaber the problem, as Kai said is that RN forces you to specify at least one dimension for network images, therefore I would need to know how to set the width relative to the size of the parent

Comment: use flex: 1; without height will do that
image: {
        flex: 1,
        aspectRatio: 1/1,
    },
    imageContainer: {
        flex: 1 / 3,
        height: 120,
    }
check here https://snack.expo.io/@ahmed_gaber/sponaneous-tortillas

Comment: "RN forces you to specify at least one dimension"  also  flex will work as the same

Comment: @AhmedGaber I do not want to use fixed sizes, that's the point of the question, it's the same if I set the height of the image or the imageContainer. I would like to set the height to be a 1:1 ratio of the width, which I want to be set as a relative of the screen width or parent component

Comment: Ok I understand now, use fixed size but calculate it based on screen with ===> screenWidth / columns, you can get screen width from here https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions

Comment: @AhmedGaber thank you this solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I solved it by using useWindowDimensions and fetching the window size and dividing it by 3. This is the codethat I used to set the style:

```
const imageWidth = Math.floor(useWindowDimensions().width/3);


style={{width:imageWidth, aspectRatio:1/1, flex:1, height:imageWidth}}
```